# How to change the order of ContextMenu in VC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shell-extensions

I'm trying to add a context menu when right click a file in explorer.

```
IFACEMETHODIMP FContextMenuExt::QueryContextMenu(
HMENU hMenu, UINT indexMenu, UINT idCmdFirst, UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags)
{
    ...
    InsertMenuItem(hMenu, 0, TRUE, &mii);
    ...
}
```

The menu was added, but did not place the menu on top. It seems on the 5th or 6th place.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: If I recall correctly the list of context menus is enumerated in the order in which they are listed in the registry (I think this was with XP so it may have changed since then).  The custom context menus will always appear after the standard ones.

Comment: @Luke in shellex\ContextMenuHandlers , WinRar listed in the end, but showed on top of my menu. Standard menu such as copy,cut etc are listed on bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to provide a position for your context menu items. Shell builds context menu with items/commands it obtains from several sources: its own GUI items, context menu handlers, registry commands etc. A context menu handler is requested to add its commands to a menu being built, and menu owner continues with adding items, including on top of the menu.

You could possibly set a hook to intercept menu popup and update it before it is shown to user and after it is completely built, but again - this is not what you are really supposed to do.

Comment: "Imagine if two applications did this."